# Is it possible to create Eclipse.Desktop file of already installed Eclipse with ADT in ubuntu?

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

I downloaded ADT Bundle and eclipse came bundled with it. I later installed PyDev for python works. Now a common problem has occurred and eclipse in not showing up menus when clicking them.

A workaround I found was to edit the Eclipse.Desktop file but in my case there is no such file in the location /usr/share/applications/ . Is there a workaround for this problem or can we create Eclipse.Desktop file for already installed eclipse?

PS : I have Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is a workaround for your problem and you can create a eclipse.desktop
file if you don't have one.

1. Open up a text editor and type in the following contents:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]

   Type=Application
   Name=Eclipse
   #for ex: Icon=/home/your username/Desktop/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/eclipse/icon.xpm
   Icon=
   #for ex: Icon=/home/username/Desktop/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/eclipse/eclipse
   Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 path/to/eclipse/installation/directory/eclipse
   Terminal=false
   Categories=DEVELOPMENT;JAVA;ANDROID;
   ```

   Save it as eclipse.desktop.
2. Make eclipse.desktop executable by right clicking eclipse.desktop then in properties panel select Allow executing as program, or from terminal `chmod +x [path to eclipse.desktop]/eclipse.desktop` don't use the braces though.
3. Finally open up terminal and copy the .desktop file to usr/share/applications by typing:

   ```
   sudo cp <path to eclipse.desktop>/eclipse.desktop /usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop
   ```

   The line `env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0` solves the problem of menus not showing